# Duplicating mouse events to simultaniously control 2 or more stacked divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseevent

I am working with the google plus API for photospheres.
For showing a time lapse panorama I have set up two divs on top of each other which get iframes with the embedded panorama viewer.
Then I have set up a timer which blends over from the front to the back div and it all works fine.

I have set it up here [on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N2d7t/1/)

My problem is, that those panoramas are interactive so you can click in it, drag it around and click again to resume autorotate or use the mouse wheel to zoom in or out. The moment I do that my two panoramas are no longer in sync so the "illusion" of time lapse does not work any more.

Is there a way to duplicate all mouse events and send them to both divs at the same time?
I was able to register clicks using jquery and

```
$('#firstDiv').click(function(){$('#seconddiv').click()})
```

but I am struggling to replicate the mouse dragging and wheel zooming to keep the two panoramas in sync.

Comment: This is using cross domain iframes so i would say it is not possible

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe give this variation a shot:

```
$('#firstDiv).on('click', function(){
    $('#secondDiv').trigger('click');
});
```

But it seems that the interactive controls for the sphere are handled on the google side. So, unless there's a callback option (by passing a query string parameter to the iframe) to enable explicit control, I'd say it's not possible.

Comment: That is the conclusion I came to. With the panoramas being displayed I can't even register a click in the div or the iframe at all.
As far as I know there is no callback of any kind available.